# MySQL Workbench Synchronize Model doesn't update source

Tags: mysql, workbench

I have been using Workbench happily for years, then Synchronize Model stopped working.  When fetching the table list from the Source not all of the tables show up.  I have tried creating a new Model and Reverse Engineering.  This creates the correct schema, but trying to synchronize again tables that exist in the source do not appear so updates to those tables are not applied.
[Source tables exits but not seen in sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKlXv.png)

Comment: I should note that I have updated to Workbench 6.3.9, the server is running MySQL 5.7, and I have created a new schema on the server and attempted to sync with the same issue.  After the schema is created, Workbench doesn't see the tables it just created.